# In NextAuth, what triggers the route to "/api/auth/signout"?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks, next.js, next-auth

In NextJS/NextAuth when a user signs out, they get randomly served the following page (screenshot below) at `localhost:3000/api/auth/signout`, however this is inconsistent (doesn't happen all the time).

[image]

When the user triggers the `signOut` method I don't want the confirmation page and want it to just immediately sign the user out. How do I go about this?

```
import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
<button onClick={ () => signOut }> </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

you are not calling the function.  From [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#:%7E:text=signOut()%E2%80%8B&text=It%20reloads%20the%20page%20in%20the%20browser%20when%20complete.)

> In order to logout, use the signOut() method to ensure the user ends
> back on the page they started on after completing the sign out flow.
> It also handles CSRF tokens for you automatically.
>
> It reloads the page in the browser when complete.

```
  // signOut()
  <button onClick={ () => signOut() }> </button>
```

`signOut` also accepts params:

```
export interface SignOutParams<R extends boolean = true> {
    /** @docs https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl-1 */
    callbackUrl?: string;
    /** @docs https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#using-the-redirect-false-option-1 */
    redirect?: R;
}
```

you can define those options, maybe redirect the user to home page